# "Scrolling" aligned equations of two rows

Tags: beamer

I'm reworking some slides so that the text is \Huge.

In reformatting the aligned equations, I only have space for 2 rows and I'd like a line or two or text underneath the aligns that explain what's the manipulation was. As of now, I have the equations moving down but I'd want a "scrolling" effect where the 2 rows stay in place.

So far, I have this but it seems that the aligns always take up the same space, even though they're only shown on their particular slides. (Ideally, it would also be great if the old equation row was gray text, so the current slide's text is focused upon.)

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}


{ \Huge
\begin{align*}
    \only<1-2>{1} \\
    \only<2-3>{2} \\
    \only<3-4>{3} \\
    \only<4-5>{4} 
\end{align*}}

    \only<1>{Text1}
    \only<2>{Text2}
    \only<3>{Text3}
    \only<4>{Text4} 
    \only<5>{Text5} 

 \end{frame}
 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use  `\only<1-2>{1} \\` you will only remove the number from the slide, but it will still add a line to the `align` as the `\\` is still there:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercovered{dynamic}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}


{ \Huge
\begin{align*}
    \only<1>{\invisible{0}\\}
    \only<1-2>{\uncover<1>{1}\\} 
    \only<2-3>{\uncover<2>{2}\\} 
    \only<3-4>{\uncover<3>{3}\\} 
    \only<4-5>{4\\} 
    \only<5>{\invisible{5}\\}
\end{align*}

}

    \only<1>{Text1}
    \only<2>{Text2}
    \only<3>{Text3}
    \only<4>{Text4} 
    \only<5>{Text5} 

 \end{frame}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks -- I'll have to test this out but it's basically perfect!

Comment: @Ally You're welcome!